# The power is going to my head: (Is my close vote decisive?)

Tags: discussion, privileges

So, the other day, I apparently closed a question all by myself:

[How do I write romance if I've never been in love?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/49379/how-do-i-write-romance-if-ive-never-been-in-love)

I've never had that power before --not sure I like having it.

However, today, under similar circumstances, my close vote seemed only to rank like anyone else's:

[When Truth Meets Fiction](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/52671/when-truth-meets-fiction)

Can anyone explain?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have a [gold tag-badge](https://writing.stackexchange.com/help/badges/139/creative-writing) in the [creative-writing](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/creative-writing) tag.

Gold badge holders have the privilege of being able to unilaterally close questions as duplicates which have the relevant tag.

For questions without the tag - your vote is no different to anyone elses.

Gold tag badge holders have powers very similar to those of moderators in those questions.

Comment: Fascinating! I'll have to be judicious with my --relatively --new powers :D

Comment: @ChrisSunamisupportsMonica I've adjusted the answer slightly - this decision for closure will only be decisive should you be voting to close it as a duplicate. For the full rules, please see the related question on [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230865/increase-close-vote-weight-for-gold-tag-badge-holders).

Comment: I asked 6 years ago if (network wide) we could be reminded when our close votes are binding. https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/231625/147247